# Is there a way to create a 'sticky' on a github's Issues page?

Tags: github

Getting a flood of the same issues posted after an os upgrade broke something and no current solution at the moment and people are skipping past the readme page. Is there a way to create a sticky at the top of the Issues page of a github issues page to reduce the influx of duplicate reports?

Answer (score 3):

Github has no good solution to this. If you create a `CONTRIBUTING.md` then github will display a [banner on the "new issue" page](https://github.com/Cockatrice/Cockatrice/issues/new) suggesting that the reporter reads it, but unfortunately if they're already on that page they're unlikely to read it.

I'd suggest proactively reaching out to your community - forums, email, twitter, blog, reddit, whatever will reach them.

Other than that you'll just have to close a bunch of tickets as duplicates. It will help to have one very detailed ticket with information for people to refer to when you close them.

This is based on my experience with a somewhat large project in a similar situation.

Comment: Thx for the `CONTRIBUTING.md` file tip.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good practice to write an instruction about "The right way to report a bug". It should explain users how to search for an existing issue before creating a new one. A link is then put to the top of readme and on the wiki home page. ([example 1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), [example 2](https://github.com/consulo/consulo/wiki/How-do-I-report-a-bug-in-Consulo))

As for sticky issues - no way.

Answer (score 1):

Since February 2016, you have "[Issue and Pull Request templates](https://github.blog/2016-02-17-issue-and-pull-request-templates/)"

> Now project maintainers can add templates for Issues and Pull Requests to projects, helping contributors share the right details at the start of a thread

[image: issue template]

Those templates are [files like `issue_template.md`](https://help.github.com/articles/manually-creating-a-single-issue-template-for-your-repository/) that you add to your gitHub repository.

That means you can add instructions/warnings in said template, in order for anyone creating a new issue to *have to* read them.

Said instructions/warnings can include:

- a general instruction about searching for duplicate issues first
- a warning about a specific issue which is reported a lot and is already followed in issue xxx.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why nobody has mentioned [pinning issues](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/pinning-an-issue-to-your-repository). Up to 3 issues can be pinned, and they will appear prominently at the top of the issues list, like [here](https://github.com/projecthamster/hamster-shell-extension/issues).